# How to reach variables from initializing method in WinForms?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list, methods

To explain my problem more clearly than the title probably do. Here's a code example:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public static List<PictureBox> listPictureBox;

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray = {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3};
    }

    public static bool testMethod
    {
        listPictureBox = new List<PictureBox>();

        for(int i = 0; i < ?????; i++) //The questionmarks should be pictureBoxArray.Length, but I don't know how to reach the code.
        {
            listPictureBox.Add(?????[i]; //Same here, the questionmarks should be pictureBoxArray.
        }
    }
```

I hope that make the question more clear.

Comment: You can't access instance variables from a static context. What exactly are you trying to achieve with the listPictureBox?

Comment: I want to be able to switch colour on the pictureboxes using the list. This should be handled by another class and will send for the bool which will perform this.

Comment: Ok. So your problem is almost certainly the "static" keyword on your method (and your field). If you want to change the colour on a *specific instance* of your TestForm, it's likely to be unproductive trying to do so from a static context. I suggest reading up on what "static" means so you can be sure you understand correctly (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx), then figure out a way to get a reference to a specific instance of your TestForm to the object that's doing the manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the static keyword for the `List<PictureBox>` and the corresponding `testMethod`.

A static variable or a static method belong to every instances of that class.
So they cannot access the instance variables specific for every class.

As a first try you should change your class to

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public static List<PictureBox> listPictureBox;

    // Make this instance variable public 
    public  PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray;

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // prepare the array with the 3 local pictureboxes
        pictureBoxArray = new PictureBox[] {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3};
    }

    // Calling this method requires that you pass the form instance where the 3 pictureboxes 
    // have been created
    public static bool testMethod(TestForm instance)
    {
        listPictureBox = new List<PictureBox>();

        for(int i = 0; i < instance.pictureBoxArray.Length; i++) 
        {
            listPictureBox.Add(instance.pictureBoxArray[i]; 
        }
    }

}
```

You call this method without specifying the instance

```
TestForm t = new TestForm();
TestForm.testMethod(t);
```

However at this point I am asking myself if you really  need this code.....

Comment: This gives me the error: "The name 'instance' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Did you add the parameter `TestForm instance` at the testMethod?

Comment: To explain the thing I want to do more clearly, I want to use the bool method to change the colour of the four first indexes in the list, and when its called for the second time it would be index 4-8 etc. (in my exaple there's only 3 indexes, but I have 50 in mine).

Comment: Well, this is a different problem then. You need another variable to keep track of your actual change position in the array between calls. Now, if this answer resolves your initial problem I suggest to write a new question where you explain this second problem.

Comment: Adding TestForm instance, which I had'nt done, gives me a new error. "An object reference is required for a non-static field, method or property" pointing at the TestForm.testMethod(t);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
     public List<PictureBox> listPictureBox;
     PictureBox[] pictureBoxArray = default(PictureBox[]);

     public TestForm()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         pictureBoxArray = new PictureBox[] {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3};
     }

     public bool testMethod()
     {
           listPictureBox = new List<PictureBox>();

         for(int i = 0; i < pictureBoxArray.length; i++) 
         {
             listPictureBox.Add(pictureBoxArray[i]); 
         }

         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this doesnt do it. I get the error message "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property."